# Calling javascript causes my controls to not render

Tags: javascript, c#

I've got the following lines of JavaScript:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MedIntakeMain.aspx.cs" Inherits="THNDPL_New.MedIntakeMain" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>Medical Intake Daily Production Log</title>

</head>

<body id="PageBody" runat="server">
   <script type = "text/javascript">
       /* Stop, Clear and Pause the timer displayed under the pause buttons  */
       var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
           start = document.getElementById('start'),
           stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
           clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
           seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
           t;

       function add() {
           seconds++;
           if (seconds >= 60) {
               seconds = 0;
               minutes++;
               if (minutes >= 60) {
                   minutes = 0;
                   hours++;
               }
           }

           document.getElementById('<%=h1.ClientID%>').innerText = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);;
       timer();
   }
   function timer() {
       t = setTimeout(add(), 1000);
   }

   function stp() {
       clearTimeout(t);
   }

   function clr() {
       document.getElementById('<%=h1.ClientID%>').innerText = "00:00:00"; 
             seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0; 
          }

</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:toolkitscriptmanager runat="server"></asp:toolkitscriptmanager>
.
.
etc...
```

When I add this to my OnClick event of a button, everything disappears:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel4, this.GetType(), "stopscript", "stp();", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel4, this.GetType(), "clearscript", "clr();", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel4, this.GetType(), "timerscript", "timer();", true);
```

UpdatePanel4 does exist, and looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="h1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black"><time>00:00:00</time></asp:Label>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If I look at the source for the page, it shows all my controls are there (textboxes, dropdowns, buttons, etc...), but they're not rendering.

Any ideas why that might happen?

Comment: Have you looked at your console for errors?

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a moron, how would I do that?  I've had no formal training so I never learned basics.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Please avoid curses or various other strong language on SO.

Comment: @JohnnyBones open the developer tools in your browser.  Usually F12 is a shortcut key.

Comment: @JohnnyBones to expand on ryanyuyu's answer. On modern browsers the key is normally F12 to open developer tools. Then find the console tab and click on it. It will show any errors on the page. You can refresh the page to display them as they occur.

Comment: I'm getting "Out of stack space" errors.  Is there any way to step through  javascript to figure out why that's happening?